# Working with caches in android using volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to receive sever data ONLY when connected to the internet. Everything works fine (fetching data, displaying data) also caching the data received is fine.

The Only issue I get is when the internet is on.

The data I get/displayed is from both the server and the cached one and I can't seem to find a way to display ONLY sever data when internet is on and cache when internet is OFF.

```
private void NotesView() {

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SERVER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                    //looping through the array

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            //errors

        }
    }){
        //offline availability cache for 24 hours
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            try {
                Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                if (cacheEntry == null) {
                    cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                }
                final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
                final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
                final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
                cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                String headerValue;
                headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                if (headerValue != null) {
                    cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                }
                headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                if (headerValue != null) {
                    cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                }
                cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;

                final String string = new String(response.data,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(string, cacheEntry);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
            super.deliverResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
            return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
        }

        @Override
        public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
            super.deliverError(error);
        }
        //get current user id
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            User user=PreferenceManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUser();
            int id=user.getId();

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", String.valueOf(id));

            return params;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}
```

When connected to the Internet I want to get server response only and not the cached data.

Answer (score 0):

`if(connected()) { stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);}` just mAke your connected method which returns true if connected to internet..

Comment: what about when am offline.... because i dont get the latest data that i have added....cause  of    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);    no cache is stored again   @Santanu Sur

Comment: in else part setShouldCache to true

Comment: it displays the previous cached data and not the latest